# Excel sheet in Microsoft excel interop. Save an image to a file

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have installed EPPlus in my c# project and used it to locate the proper image in an Excel worksheet.  I want to take the image now and save it as a PNG file.

```
 FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"c:/folder/workbook.xlsx");
 using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fi))
  {
   ExcelWorksheet ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
   int imageCount = firstWorksheet.Drawings.Count;
   for (int i = 0; i <= imageCount-1; i++)
    {
       if (firstWorksheet.Drawings[i].DrawingType.ToString().ToLower() == "picture")
        {
         save it to a file;
        }
    }
  }
```

Here is what I did that works great.  Of course this is a little abbreviated.

OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelDrawing image = firstWorksheet.Drawings[i];
OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelPicture p = (OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelPicture)image;
p.Image.Save(@"c:/autocell/becbec.png");

This works with embedded xml files / tables.  I also pasted in jpegs and pngs and bitmaps and this code found and saved them just fine too.

Comment: May you please provide your best try which didn't work for you?

Comment: My spreadsheet has an embedded bitmap image in it.  I can find the bitmap using the EPPlus C# code snippet above.  To your point, now that I have the image as ws.Drawings[i], can not determine how to save it as an external file.  So unfortunately I have not made a "best try".  Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: I renamed the spreadsheet to .zip and extracted all from it.  In the resulting /xl/drawings/ folder I found my drawing and it is, in fact an XML table. That being said, I have still not figured out how to get it out programmatically.  I ultimately need to get it into a PNG file because it has to be stored in the amazon cloud and later used by another application.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the export URL and then it will be shown in the excel file

Get Absolute URL function

```
private string GetAbsoluteUrl(string relativeUrl)
{
    relativeUrl = relativeUrl.Replace("~/", string.Empty);
    string[] splits = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('/');
    if (splits.Length >= 2)
    {
        string url = splits[0] + "//";
        for (int i = 2; i < splits.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            url += splits[i];
            url += "/";
        }
 
        return url + relativeUrl;
    }
    return relativeUrl;
}
```

and save it like this

//Convert the Relative Url to Absolute Url and set it to Image control.

`Image1.ImageUrl = this.GetAbsoluteUrl(Image1.ImageUrl);`

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"c:/folder/workbook.xlsx");
 using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fi))
  {
   ExcelWorksheet ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
   int imageCount = firstWorksheet.Drawings.Count;
   for (int i = 0; i <= imageCount-1; i++)
    {
       if (firstWorksheet.Drawings[i].DrawingType.ToString().ToLower() == 
            "picture")
        {
         // save it to a file;
         OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelDrawing image = firstWorksheet.Drawings[i]; 
         OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelPicture p = 
         (OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelPicture)image; 
         p.Image.Save(@"c:/autocell/becbec.png");
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).